# Not able to marry Web API core with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two projects: the first one on Web API core and the second one on Angular 8.1.1.
I am having a problem with displaying Web API request results in Angular. I am not able to send them properly to Angular.

I am able to see Web API get result opening the URL `http://localhost:49384/api/theatre directly in the browser.`

I send in this URL to Angular as

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class TheatreService {
  private theatreUrl = 'api/theatre';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getTheatre(): Observable<Theatre[]> {
    return this.http.get<Theatre[]>(this.theatreUrl)
  }
}
```

I haved created proxy server to have common localhost
proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api/*":
  {
    "target": "http//localhost:49384",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and added "proxyConfig" to angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "TicketSalePointUI:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
```

I am getting the following error "GET `http://localhost:4200/api/theatre 404 (Not Found)"`

Do you have any ideas what I could be doing wrong?
Many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are making request to

```
http://localhost:4200/api/theatre
```

which is not found. So you have to change your port number to 49384

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class TheatreService {
  private theatreUrl = 'http://localhost:49384/api/theatre';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getTheatre(): Observable<Theatre[]> {
    return this.http.get<Theatre[]>(this.theatreUrl)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//You have to import following

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Student} from "client/models";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  baseUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44358/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getStudents(): Observable<Array<Student>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Student>>(`${this.baseUrl}/Student`);
  }
}
```

import {Student} from "client/models" is a model which I am using for binding the response from API